# По какой причине popup ломается? | js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, frontend, popup

**При открытии** первого раза popup всё подгружается правильно. Ниже представлено нормальное поведение popup'a со скедулером (расписанием):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container dhx_scheduler_agenda" style="width:100%; height:440px; border: 1px solid #CECECE;" role="application">
    <div class="dhx_cal_navline" style="width: 871px; height: 59px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
        <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button" role="button" aria-label="Previous">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_next_button" role="button" aria-label="Next">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_today_button" aria-label="Today" role="button">Today</div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab dhx_cal_tab_first" name="day_tab" style="right: auto; left: 14px;" aria-label="Day" role="button" aria-pressed="false">Day</div>
        u<div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab" style="right: auto; left: 75px;" aria-label="Week" role="button" aria-pressed="false">Week</div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab dhx_cal_tab_last" name="month_tab" style="right: auto; left: 136px;" aria-label="Month" role="button" aria-pressed="false">Month</div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab dhx_cal_tab_standalone" name="year_tab" style="right: auto; left: 211px;" aria-label="Year" role="button" aria-pressed="false">Year</div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab dhx_cal_tab_standalone active" name="agenda_tab" style="right: auto; left: 297px;" aria-label="Agenda" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Agenda</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_header" style="width: 871px; height: 20px; left: -1px; top: 60px;"><div role="row" class="dhx_agenda_line"><div role="columnheader" aria-label="Date">Date</div><span style="padding-left:25px" role="columnheader" aria-label="Description">Description</span></div></div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_data" style="width: 871px; height: 357px; left: 0px; top: 81px;"><div class="dhx_agenda_area" role="grid"><div aria-label=" Event: New event Start date: 2019-09-04 00:00 End date: 2019-09-04 00:05" aria-selected="false" role="row" class="dhx_agenda_line" event_id="1567497352597" style=""><div class="dhx_agenda_event_time">4 Sep 2019 00:00</div><div role="button" aria-label="Details" class="dhx_event_icon icon_details">&nbsp;</div><span>New event</span></div><div aria-label=" Event: New event Start date: 2019-09-10 00:00 End date: 2019-09-10 00:05" aria-selected="false" role="row" class="dhx_agenda_line" event_id="1567497352604" style=""><div class="dhx_agenda_event_time">10 Sep 2019 00:00</div><div role="button" aria-label="Details" class="dhx_event_icon icon_details">&nbsp;</div><span>New event</span></div><div aria-label=" Event: New event Start date: 2019-09-11 00:00 End date: 2019-09-11 00:05" aria-selected="false" role="row" class="dhx_agenda_line" event_id="1567497352605" style=""><div class="dhx_agenda_event_time">11 Sep 2019 00:00</div><div role="button" aria-label="Details" class="dhx_event_icon icon_details">&nbsp;</div><span>New event</span></div><div class="dhx_v_border" style="height: 100%;"></div></div></div>
</div>
```

---

**Однако,** открывая повторно тот же popup, данные не подгружаются, даже встроенные стили:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style="width:100%; height:440px; border: 1px solid #CECECE;">
    <div class="dhx_cal_navline">
        <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_today_button"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="day_tab" style="right:204px;"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab" style="right:140px;"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="month_tab" style="right:76px;"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="year_tab" style="right:280px;"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="agenda_tab" style="right:280px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_header"></div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_data"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Cтили**, которые должны подргужаться,
сверху - сломанный popup
снизу - рабочий
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Прекрасно** понимаю, что дать сразу однозначный ответ крайне трудно. Возможно, вы с таким сталкивались, вот ссылка на документацию конкретно этого участка кода: https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/initialization.html

Comment: У вас явно проблема в инициализации по этому и нет ни стилей ничего другого, нужно смотреть в сторону выполнения скрипта, т.к. вы говорите что 1-ый раз всё норм, а второй уже не работает инициализация самого компонента а не шедула

Comment: @Vearo код картинкой скинули для наглядности, сверху верстка а снизу таже верстка только когда компонент инициализируется и нормально как на 1-ом скрине показывается! Код вместо картинки ничего не скажет!

Comment: @RifmaMan на каком-то этапе инициализации, как эффективнее найти место, где проблема с инициализацией?

Comment: @Lancelot после открытия и работы компонента может потребоваться уничтожить данные и при повторном открытии через шедул вы видимо что-то пропускаете, нужно смотреть документацию и отладчик, удаленно к сожалению я никак не могу подсказать

Comment: А что здесь делает метка "css" ?