# Как подчищать структуру DOM-дерева?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, frontend

В процессе работы PopUp создаётся и накапливается неактивный код, который приводит к [багу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1020883/). Попробовал его руками удалить и всё начало работать.

Как правильно можно убрать неактивные блоки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

upd. Это код открытого PopUp. Вызывается через свойство:

```
...
template: window.template;
...
```

---

```
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close()" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{'TITLE' | translate}}</h4>
        </div>

        <div ng-controller="FormCtrl">
            <tabset class="form-container">
                <tab ng-repeat="form in model.forms" heading="{{form.name}}" ng-click="model.onTabSelect(tabs.TAB, form)">
                    <div data-ng-model="model.selectedTheme" data-theme="model.theme" data-name="form.name"></div>
                </tab>
            </tabset>
            <div>
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div ng-model="input" fb-form="{{IDENTIFIER}}"></div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" ng-click="onSaveClick()" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><span ng-bind-template="{{'CONFIRM_OK' | translate}}"></span></button>
            <button type="button" ng-click="close('CANCEL')" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span ng-bind-template="{{'CONFIRM_CANCEL' | translate}}"></span></button>
        </div>
```

upd2. @free_ze правильно подметил на счёт закрытия элемента. По неизвестной причине данный код скрывает, но не очищает код из dom-дерева, хотя на других PopUp работает впорядке.

```
.then(function (modal) {
                    modal.element.modal();
                    return modal.close;
                });
```

upd3. Корнем проблемы является отсутствие вызова "angular-model-service.js". В других случаях все PopUp вызывают $destroy и remove(), кроме текущего.

```
var modal = {
              controller: modalController,
              scope: modalScope,
              element: modalElement,
              close: closeDeferred.promise
            };

              //  When close is resolved, we'll clean up the scope and element.
              modal.close.then(function(result) {
              //  Clean up the scope
              modalScope.$destroy();
              //  Remove the element from the dom.
              modalElement.remove();
            });
```

Comment: не создавать их?

Comment: @PauloBerezini расскажите поподробнее, слишком неоднозначный ответ и могу неправильно понять

Comment: это ведь ангуляр. как вы создаете эти локи? компонент попапа ваш?

Comment: @ThisMan не конкретно мой, он уже был написан. Это не часть какой-то библиотеки. Как они создаются - не знаю, это часть вопроса.

Comment: _это часть вопроса._ и как по вашему мы должны не зная кода ответить по скриншоту на этот вопрос? Добавьте в вопрос код, где создаются эти попапы ( добавляется компонент ), потому что иначе мало что понятно

Comment: Убедитесь, что используемые компоненты создающие разметку грамотно закрываются (часто бывает необходимо позвать какой-нибудь метод, с названием вроде `destroy`).

Comment: @ThisMan посмотрите, я обновил вопрос

Comment: `return modal.close;` - а скобки где?

Comment: @Qwertiy добавил код из angular-modal-service.js . Там видно, что это промис (промис записанный через свойство?).